# Pyplot, Plot data over image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some images I've gathered, using plt.imshow(), and I would like to plot the y-axis average over the top of the image. However, I cannot figure out how to get pyplot to match the shape and borders of the image; if I plot using another axis, it'll resize the borders based on the fontsize of the tick labels of the two images.

(Note, eventually I'm going to use axes, but the keywords I'm using are hitting general axis placement questions).

Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imshow(data_array, cmap="inferno")
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.clim(0,1)
plt.show()
```

Extra information:

```
data_array.shape
(1000, 950)
```

desired plot:

```
y_average = np.average(data_array, axis=0)
```

[image]

I would like to combine it with a y line-plot for the same image
[image]

Comment: Edited. Apologies.

Comment: How should this y-axis average be presented? As an image using your cmap, a line curve, something else?

Comment: A line plot, where the position on the x-axis matches that on the heatmap.

Comment: The usual approach would be to create a [2x2 gridspec](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/arranging_axes.html#manual-adjustments-to-a-gridspec-layout) filled with lineplot, nothing, colorbar, and imshow (clockwise from top left).